# XML schema generation library

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I'm looking for some library that can parse `XML` or `XSD` files and create (even simple) `GUI` interface which is parsed schema compliant (some kind of a `GUI` editor for the schema). The user could fill it and save into `XML` file. I want to use it in my program as a module, so I can't use any external programs. I tried to find something in the Web, but still unlucky:(

Do you know any libraries such like that one? I want it in `C#` but if there are no such things written in `.NET` I could have a look at something from other language.

Comment: The problem is my app serves some `XML` standard. This standard is updated from time to time. I wanted my app to download a new `XSD` schema file and use it to create a GUI editor automatically - which is a part of a larger software.

Comment: Do you need something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3645/A-Dynamically-Generated-XML-Data-Editor) or [this](http://www.edit-xml.com/easyxmleditor.htm) ?

Comment: @MenelaosVergis Yes! I looks like a solution for my problem:))) Please, convert your comment into a new post. I will mark it green:) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple google search I came up with the following free tools:

- [XML Data Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3645/A-Dynamically-Generated-XML-Data-Editor)
- [Easy XML Editor](http://www.edit-xml.com/easyxmleditor.htm)